# O que pode ser discutido aqui no Meta?

Tags: debate, meta

Quais assuntos podem ser discutidos aqui no Meta? Por exemplo, se eu tiver uma dúvida sobre o mercado de trabalho com programação, eu posso postar aqui? Não? Tem algum outro lugar que eu poderia abrir esse tipo de discussão?

Comment: Aqui tem uma explicação: [O que é o "meta"? Como ele funciona?](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/help/whats-meta)

Comment: Entendi, obrigado Math. Mas por exemplo, se eu tivesse uma dúvida do contexto da que dei de exemplo ali em cima: "se eu tiver uma dúvida sobre o mercado de trabalho com programação" como faço? Teria algum lugar? Ou eu teria que ficar sem mesmo? :/

Comment: Pode conversar sobre isso no [chat do site](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/11910/estouro-de-pilha) sempre tem alguém lá para trocar ideias.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

Como diria Jack o Estripador, vamos por partes.

> Quais assuntos podem ser discutidos aqui no Meta?

Lembre-se sempre:

[image]

[A ajuda do site diz o seguinte:](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/help/whats-meta)

***"O Stack Overflow em Português Meta é a parte do site onde os usuários discutem o funcionamento e as políticas do Stack Overflow em Português em vez de discutir o programação em si."***

> Por exemplo, se eu tiver uma dúvida sobre o mercado de trabalho com programação, eu posso postar aqui? Não?

Não.

> Tem algum outro lugar que eu poderia abrir esse tipo de discussão?

Você pode ver todos os assuntos disponíveis na rede através do endereço https://stackexchange.com/sites. Você verá um balão para cada Stack - o tamanho de cada um representa o seu tamanho relativo na rede.

Os assuntos incluem religião, aviação, videogames, culinária etc.

Para mercado de trabalho talvez o [Workplace](https://workplace.stackexchange.com/) ajude, mas fique avisado de que o pessoal lá é tão pedante com as perguntas sobre trabalho quanto nós somos pedantes com as perguntas sobre programação aqui. E dado o perfil internacional do site, talvez perguntas específicas sobre o mercado de trabalho nos países lusófonos não obtenham tanta atenção por lá.

Para outros assuntos relacionados a TI, há stacks específicos para [Ciência da Computação Teórica](https://cstheory.stackexchange.com/), [Engenharia de Software](https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/), [Revisão de Código](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/) e [Code Golf](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/) - porém note que, dada a ausência de seus equivalentes em português, nós também abordamos esses assuntos por aqui.

Se ainda assim você tiver algum assunto que não se encaixe nos stacks, você pode tentar se juntar com outras pessoas para formar um novo stack. Existe um site na rede só para isso, a [Área 51](http://area51.stackexchange.com/).

Agora, caso o assunto não seja algo que possa ser discutido no formato de um stack, você pode tentar o Yahoo! Respostas ou o Quora, ou procurar fóruns especializados.

Comment: Show! Todos esses tem o "suporte" em português?

Comment: Não, @LucasCarvalho O único site em português da Stack Exchange é o SOpt.

Comment: E o Portuguese Language Learners

Comment: [Portuguese Language](https://portuguese.stackexchange.com/)

Comment: - *"o programação em si"* -- Eita!!! Chamem o revisor!