# Quais são as abreviações/gírias mais comuns usadas no Stack Overflow em Português?

Tags: suporte

Sou novo no **Stack Overflow<sup>pt</sup>** e gostaria de um *overview* das principais abreviações e "gírias" usadas, para não ficar perdido.

Por exemplo, me deparei com uma pergunta onde se foi usada a abreviação **AP** nos comentários, tive de ter uns 5 minutos de pesquisa para entender por cima o que significa, mas ainda não sei exatamente.

Comment: Autor da pergunta, em inglês é OP (original poster)

Comment: Creio que existam mais abreviações, por isso espero uma resposta. Mas valeu!

Comment: Tem dúvida em mais algum? acredito que criar um resposta como um glossário seria muito util.

Comment: AR - Autor da resposta

Comment: Da mesma forma que não conhecia essa abreviação, não vou conhecer qualquer outra hahahaha, um glossário seria bom mesmo.

Comment: TL;DR - *Too long; didn't read* -  usado por alguém que escreveu uma grande resposta, ou o que quer que seja para mostrar um breve resumo de sua publicação, pois pode ser muito longo.

Comment: RELACIONADA: [O que é OP?](https://pt.meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/2649/70)

Answer (score 33, accepted):

- #### AP

  Autor da pergunta.
- #### AR

  Autor da resposta.
- #### OP

  [**Do inglês**] *Original poster/post*.

  Pode se referir tanto a um post que deu origem a uma *thread*, quando ao redator do *post*. Geralmente usamos AP/AR no lugar deste.
- #### MCVE

  [**Do inglês**] *Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example*. Ou seja, **exemplo Mínimo, Completo e Verificável**.

  Você pode ler sobre esta [abreviação na central de ajuda](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).
- #### TL;DR;

  [**Do inglês**] *Too long, didn't read* **ou** alguma variação disto.

  Geralmente (aqui no site) usamos para dar uma explicação breve de algo que será detalhado posteriormente. Isso é bastante corriqueiro em respostas que são muito grandes.
- #### SO

  **S**tack **O**verflow. Usamos para nos referir aos sites *hermanos* do SOpt - incluindo o próprio. Também pode ser usado para se referir à empresa, dado a [mudança de nome "recente"](https://pt.meta.stackoverflow.com/q/4354/18246).
- #### SOpt

  **S**tack **O**verflow em **P**or**t**uguês. Nosso querido site.
- #### SOen, SOes, SOjp (ou SOja) e SOru

  Usamos para nos referir aos sites irmãos. Respectivamente, [Stack Overflow (em inglês)](https://stackoverflow.com/), [Stack Overflow em Español](https://es.stackoverflow.com/), [スタック・オーバーフロ](https://ja.stackoverflow.com/) e [Stack Overflow на русском](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/).
- #### SE

  StackExchange. Usamos para nos referir à rede de sites a qual os StackOverflow's (dentre vários outros) pertencem. Também pode ser usado para se referir à empresa, já que este era o nome dela anteriormente.
- #### Q&A

  [**Do inglês**] *Questions & Answers*. Se refere ao formato do site - perguntas e respostas. Vide: [O Stack Overflow em Português é um fórum?](https://pt.meta.stackoverflow.com/q/2068/18246)
- #### Meta

  Este site usado para debater sobre o StackOverflow em Português. Todos os sites da rede têm um meta, então falar "o meta" pode ser dependente de contexto. Vide: [O que pode ser discutido aqui no Meta?](https://pt.meta.stackoverflow.com/q/6130/18246)
- #### Metão ou MSE

  O [lugar para discutir](https://meta.stackexchange.com/) sobre todos os sites da rede. A maioria das alterações, melhorias, bugs e planos malignos para dominar o mundo que são de interesse de **todos os sites da rede** estão lá.
- #### CM

  [**Do inglês**] *Community Manager*. É o nome dado aos funcionários da empresa que têm como objetivo "cuidar" dos sites da rede.

Comment: Valeu manow, era bem isso que precisava!

Comment: Pode acrescentar CM (Community Manager), como o Gabe.

Comment: +1 Está ótimo, as mais comuns estão adicionadas, pode até existir outas que não nos lembramos, mas provavelmente são incomuns

Comment: @JorgeB. SU = superuser.com :D

Comment: @GuilhermeNascimento SUpt?! :D

Comment: @JorgeB. kakaka o Gabe confirmou que teremos :P

Comment: Além desses @LINQ, acho que *CW* / WC, Rel/Rela, Dup, *Rollback*, *On* / *Off* *Topic*.

Comment: @UzumakiArtanis nunca vi CW/WC (wc é banheiro? hehehe) e Rel/Rela (deve ser de "relacionado", mas nunca vi usando e não gosto muito). Os demais dup, rollback e on/off acho otimos para mencionar.

Comment: @GuilhermeNascimento, *Community Wiki* / Wiki Comunitário, respectivamente. Rel/Rela são até que frequentemente utilizados, por isso citei. Mas são somente sugestões a resposta do LINQ.

Comment: @UzumakiArtanis realmente são tão incomuns que nunca as li em lugar algum, talvez no chat seja mais comum, mas no site e comentários realmente nunca vi :/

Comment: Talvez Data.SE / Rep(Reputação), seja interessante adicionar.

Comment: @GuilhermeNascimento SUpt lá para 2099 :P

Comment: Bem essas mesmo. Quando cheguei aqui, eu achava que quando pessoal falava de SO, eu pensava que era Sistema Operacional